# form -> table -> tr using successive findAll calls

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Ok so I can reference my table correctly in a html page like this:

```
form = soup.findAll('form')[1]

table = form.findAll('table', width="79%")  # returns 1 table, doing a print shows table with rows

tr = table.findAll('tr')
```

I get an error:

*ResultSet object has no attribute findAll.*

Why doesn't this work?  I used the output of form.findAll to get the table, and the table (using print) does indeed have table rows etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the previous question, `findAll` returns a list.

So,

```
table = form.findAll('table', width='79%')[0]
tr = table.findAll(...)
```

will extract the first one.  As before, check that your list isn't empty first.

Comment: But I did a len(table) and it was 1?  I guess I still ahve to do [0] ok I get it.

Comment: Right, len(table) just gives you the length.  Once you know it's > 0, then extract the element with the index ([0] gets the first one).